# Problems with WCF WebReference on c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

Im using a WebService (WCF) on a C# android Xamarin Project. I use this code to Intilize the service.

```
 private void InitializedService1Client()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();
        ClienteServicio = new Service1Client(binding, Endpoint);
        ClienteServicio.ConsStatusCompleted += ClienteServicio_ConsStatusCompleted;
    }
```

Ass you can see I create the EventHandler for consStatuscompleted, when is completeed I use  this code.

```
private void ClienteServicio_ConsStatusCompleted(object sender, ConsStatusCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == true && Vdispositivo == "Alarma")
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() => this.Btnestado.Text = "On");
            Vpool = true;
        }
        else
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() => this.Btnestado.Text = "Off");
            Vpool = false;
        }

        if (e.Result == true && Vdispositivo == "Sala1")
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() => this.BtnSala1.Text = "On");
            Vpool = true;
        }
        else
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() => this.BtnSala1.Text = "Off");
            Vpool = false;
        }
    }
```

I call the Web Service with this code

```
 private void Btnestado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TxtEstado.Text = "Entrando..";
        Vdispositivo = "Alarma";
        ClienteServicio.ConsStatusAsync("Alarma");

    }
```

This are my problems.
1) The ClienteServicio.ConsStatusAsync("Alarma"); return VOID so I cant Wait to finish.
2) I need to wait to finish because I need to check other Items the First is Alarma then other but I dont Understand How.

Im new on Xamarin and C# place help me. and Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way instead:

```
private async void Btnestado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TxtEstado.Text = "Entrando..";
    Vdispositivo = "Alarma";

    BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();
    var svc = new Service1Client(binding, Endpoint);

    var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync<string, bool>(
        svc.BeginConsStatus,
        svc.EndConsStatus,
        "Alarma", null);

    var result = await task;

    if (result == true && Vdispositivo == "Alarma") {
        this.Btnestado.Text = "On";
        Vpool = true;
    } else {
        this.Btnestado.Text = "Off";
        Vpool = false;
    }

    if (result == true && Vdispositivo == "Sala1") {
        this.BtnSala1.Text = "On";
        Vpool = true;
    } else {
        this.BtnSala1.Text = "Off";
        Vpool = false;
    }
}
```

Note the use of `Task.Factory.FromAsync<T1, T2>()` with the Begin/End form of async calls instead of the event-based async you were using previously.

Comment: Hi Thks for your Answer, when I write svc.BeginConsStatus, I get an error telling me that "Error CS1061 'Service1Client' does not contain a definition for 'BeginConsStatus' and no extension method 'BeginConsStatus' accepting a first argument of type 'Service1Client' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) HCAndroid E:\programas\Android\HCAndroid\HCAndroid\FrmEstado.cs 57 Active"

Comment: Im reading about Task.Factory.FromAsync But Don understand what are my BeginConStatus and my Endconstatus, can you help me to understand

Comment: If your web service client was created using the Add Service Reference option in Visual Studio, then be sure to check the box to generate async methods. Or, if you are using svcutil.exe directly, then be sure to pass the right command-line option to generate the async methods. That's what signals to the client generator that it should create Begin/End method pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the Webservice call correctly.

On ClienteServicio_ConsStatusCompleted you need to validade the server response. There is an Error object on ConsStatusCompletedEventArgs. If it's null, the request was sucessfull and you get the response in Result object, and an Exception on Error object if there was some error.

When you call ClienteServicio.ConsStatusAsync("Alarma") you need to show some Loading dialog, and dismiss it at ClienteServicio_ConsStatusCompleted and keep doing your stuff from there.

Ex: (Seens you speak portuguese, so the method names are so)

```
ClienteServicio.ConsStatusCompleted += ClienteServicio_ConsStatusCompleted;
ClienteServicio.ConsStatusAsync("Alarma");
mostraDialogoProcessando();

...

private void ClienteServicio_ConsStatusCompleted(object sender, ConsStatusCompletedEventArgs e){

    escondeDialogoProcessamento();
    if(e.Error != null){
       mostraErro(e);
       return;
    }
    restoDoProgramaAPartirDaqui(e.Result);
}
```

OBS: Create a Task that runs ClienteServicio.ConsStatus (not Async) may block your UI.

Comment: Thks for the response, The problem Im having is that I need to wait for the webservice to end in order to continue, Ex. I need to check y "Alarma" and "Sala" are active with the webservice  ClienteServicio.ConsStatusAsync(device) and the web service only show me ClienteServicio.ConsStatusAsync("Alarma") as ASYNC and return VOID, so I dont know how to wait for this to end in order to check the next device.

Comment: Just don't await. Check "Alarma" em "Sala" on the ConsStatusCompleted. But should be an syncronous method 'ClienteServicio.ConsStatus'. In theory, you can create a task that runs this method and await the task to terminate. But when I tried this, the UI thead was loked.

Comment: The problem is my webreference dont have a sync method only the async one, I can check 1 device at a time but if I do a loop to check all the devices the status buttons dont get the correct value becouse the lack of await.